# Python sympy module problems

Tags: python, sympy

I met some problems when I using sympy to solve mathematical  problems, my code is like this,

```
eq1=Eq(0, -sympy.sqrt(x**2) + sympy.sqrt((x + 4)**2))
sympy.solve(eq1,x)
```

the answer for this equation ought to be -2, but I got an empty list instead

Comment: `solve` doesn't guarantee giving all the solutions to an equation. An empty list can mean it has no solutions or it could just mean no solutions were found. `solveset` does try to give all the solutions, meaning sometimes it can give a generic set if it can't determine if all solutions were found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eq1=Eq(0, -sympy.sqrt(x**2) + sympy.sqrt((x + 4)**2))
sympy.solveset(eq1,x)
```

this should work

**OUTPUT**

```
{-2}
```

btw sympy got an exelent website that would have given you the answer, along with a very intuitive shell inside the browser https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html

here is what sympy has to say on the matter:

"Please note that there is another function called solve which can also be used to solve equations. The syntax is solve(equations, variables) However, it is recommended to use solveset instead."